# Replace specific parts of string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this:

```
$string = '[some_block title="any text" aaa="something" desc="anytext" bbb="something else"]';
```

I need to replace the text between the quotes for both title= and desc=

The order of the title and desc can change, meaning desc could be before title, or there could be other things like aaa= or bbb= before/inbetween/after as well.

I can not use str_replace because I do not know what text will appear in the between the quotes.

I am thinking that one possible solution is that I could explode on title= and then explode on double-quote and then piece it back together with new text, and repeat for desc=

Just wondering if there is a better solution that I am not aware of for doing something like this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Regular Expressions?

Comment: @ADyson I am familar with Regular Expressions to point that they completely confuse me and I do not really understand them :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regexp php function `preg_replace`, you may add search patterns and replacement pass as two arrays:

```
$string = preg_replace([
      '/ title="[^"]+"/',
      '/ desc="[^"]+"/',
   ], [
      sprintf(' title="%s"', 'replacement'),
      sprintf(' desc="%s"', 'replacement'),
   ], $string);

    // NOTE: Space was added in front of title= and desc= 
    // EXAMPLE: If you do not have a space, then it will replace the text in the quotes for title="text-will-get-replaced" as well as something similar like enable_title="text-will-get-replaced-as-well". Adding the space will only match title= but not enable_title=
```

Comment: Although the code is quite simple and you have spaced it out nicely, it still should have some description. Such as what is regex and how it works in this case

Comment: Ok, I will make more descriptions in future.

Comment: @PavelMusil Well I don't really understand it, but it works! Thanks

Comment: So one problem I noticed is that the code will replace text in quotes for title= but also for anything_title= as well .. I have edited the code and put a space in front of title and desc so it will only replace the desired section.

Comment: Hi, this has problem with space `'_title="[^"]+"'`, if space missing. So, try use regexp pattern without space `'title="[^"]+"'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest and comparison sake, I am posting my original function as an example of "how **not** to do it".

I recommend Pavel Musil's answer using preg_replace instead of this:

```
<?php

$string = '[some_block title="any text" aaa="something" desc="anytext" bbb="something else"]';

$new_string = replaceSpecial('title=', '"', 'my new text', $string);

echo $new_string; // will output: [some_block title="my new text" aaa="something" desc="anytext" bbb="something else"]

function replaceSpecial($needle, $text_wrapper, $new_text, $haystack) {
    $new_string = $haystack;
    $needle_arr = explode($needle, $haystack, 2);
    if (count($needle_arr) > 1) {
        $wrapper_arr = explode($text_wrapper, $needle_arr[1], 3);
        $needle_arr[1] = $wrapper_arr[0].$needle.'"'.$new_text.'"'.$wrapper_arr[2];
        $new_string = $needle_arr[0].$needle_arr[1];
    }
return $new_string;
}

?>
```